# Could not find gem 'logstash-devutils (>= 0) ruby' in any of the gem sources

Tags: ruby, bundle, logstash

I'm just trying to learn to write the example-output-plugin,follow this page:

http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/_how_to_write_a_logstash_output_plugin.html#_clone_and_test_4

when I type the "bundle install" in the folder ~/logstash-output-example,I get the the error:

`Could not find gem 'logstash-devutils (>= 0) ruby' in any of the gem sources
listed in your Gemfile or installed on this machine.`

it seems the gem 'logstash-devutils (>= 0) ruby' missed,but when I type the 
"sudo gem install logstash-devutils", I get the error

`ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'logstash-devutils' (>= 0)`

Here is why:

`Found logstash-devutils (0.0.12), but was for platform java`

Anyone else can help me?

environment:MAC OSX 10.9.5

Answer (score 12):

I just ran into the same problem. Solved it by just downloading the gem via the download link on its rubygems.org page and installing it with:

```
sudo gem install logstash-devutils-0.0.13-java.gem
```

<s>That worked for me.</s>

Update:
Well, that will install the gem but it will not solve the real problem. I needed to switch to jruby for the tutorial to work. This can be done via the [RVM](https://rvm.io/):

```
sudo rvm install jruby
```

Comment: If you just installed rvm for this, you also need to exit the console window and start a new one so that it correctly pulls the environment variables.  You also should do `rvm jruby`

Comment: To add to the reply above, you can avoid closing your shell by sourcing the rvm script after install:  

    source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm  

And to use the jruby version that you installed after running `rvm install jruby` you would want to do:  

    rvm use jruby  

or  

    rvm use jruby-1.7.19

Answer (score 12):

I tried installing the gem manually and got a different error:

> There was a RuntimeError while loading logstash-devutils.gemspec:
>   Only JRuby is supported from
>     /Users/bnewton/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bundler/gems/logstash-devutils-15c59bfaab59/logstash-devutils.gemspec:2:in `'

This leads me to believe the logstash-devutils requires jruby rather than the usual ruby. I use [rvm](https://rvm.io/), so it was a matter of installing and using jruby instead of regular ruby. So if you are using rvm, run:

```
rvm install jruby-1.7.19
rvm use jruby-1.7.19
gem install bundler
bundle install
```

This fixed it for me, and I was able to run `bundle install` without error.