# ruby gem error: Could not find gem 'logstash-devutils (>= 0) x64-mingw32'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, jruby

On Windows 7, I'm following the steps in [this tutorial](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/_how_to_write_a_logstash_filter_plugin.html) from elastic

When I use the command `bundle install` I get the following error

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Could not find gem 'logstash-devutils (>= 0) x64-mingw32' in any of the gem
sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine.
```

and the following is my Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gemspec
```

Kindly note that when I used the command `gem list` I can find the `gem jquery-rails` listed there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, and I believe this will fix the problem. In a nutshell, logstash-devutils needs jruby, so trying to use regular ruby won't work.

[Could not find gem 'logstash-devutils (>= 0) ruby' in any of the gem sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29770821/could-not-find-gem-logstash-devutils-0-ruby-in-any-of-the-gem-sources/35046727#35046727)

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe I forgot to update you all about the status of my issue, that was how I fixed it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `gem 'logstash-devutils', '~> 0.0.10'` to your gemfile

Comment: is the gem installed `gem install logstash-devutils -v 0.0.10`?

Comment: No. This gives me the following: `ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'logstash-devutils' (= 0.0.10) in any repository`

Comment: I think I know what the problem is. The filter example I downloaded from elastic uses jruby, and not ruby. So I need to use jruby to install the gem, correct? Could you tell me how to specify jruby to be used and not ruby? thanks.

Comment: check the first section of Installing JRuby here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/moving-an-existing-rails-app-to-run-on-jruby

Comment: I'm using Windows so rvm to switch between ruby and jruby will not help. But what I did was remove the ruby path so jruby was being forced to be used, the used the command `gem install bundler` and then finally `bundle install` and that worked for me, and I'm no longer facing any problems. Thanks.