# ruby gem can search for, but not install some gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems, logstash

I'm currently trying to setup a ruby environment to develop a logstash plugin. This ruby installation is absolutely untouched (I've installed ruby 2.4.2 with DevKit on Windows)

I can search and find the `logstash-devutils` gem:

```
$ gem search devutils

*** REMOTE GEMS ***

devutils (0.0.1)
devutils-docs (0.0.1)
devutils-guard (0.0.1)
devutils-metrics (0.0.2)
logstash-devutils (1.3.6 java)
```

But if I try to install it I get an error:

```
$ gem install logstash-devutils
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'logstash-devutils' (>= 0) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: logstash-input-xls, logstash-input-irc, logstash-output-xls, logstash-input-sqs, logstash_rails
```

While trying to download and install the gem manually I've found some other gems with a similar behaviour (I didn't examine it until the and):

- logstash-core
- logstash-core-plugin-api
- manticore

Furthermore I get the error in 2 diffrent VMs (both linux with different ruby versions, I think 1.9.x and 2.3.x).

Also an update of `gem` itself didn't change something.

I'm not new to ruby but I've never observed something like this.

Just to make it clear: There are gems (e.g. bundler) that can be installed as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Previously asked and answered: [Could not find gem 'logstash-devutils (>= 0) ruby' in any of the gem sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29770821/could-not-find-gem-logstash-devutils-0-ruby-in-any-of-the-gem-sources)

Specifically, the `java` tag on the gem version means it requires a java-based Ruby interpreter. So the default ruby (MRI) won’t work. You need to be running [JRuby](http://jruby.org/) (which you can more easily install, and not mess with your other Ruby projects, using a Ruby manager such as [RVM](https://rvm.io/)).